# EGit equivalent for git format-patch and git am

Tags: egit, jgit

I work with some other guys over EGit, but we don't have a central place to push/pull from. Now rather than sending our entire repos each time, I'd like to use git-format-patch/am but with EGit. Is this supported?

Answer (score 1):

This is not yet supported. You can export a commit in the "email" format using the history view context menu "Create Patch...". But when applying the patch, it is not automatically committed as it would be with `git am`.

Comment: More importantly, it would diverge history on the source and target repositories I guess.